# Significantly higher outcomes in stock price predicting LSTM model than expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have made my LSTM model to estimate next day's stock prices. I have used tensorflow and keras.

However, I do not understand why my model's predicted price is almost always 2 or 3 factors higher than the current stock price. Is there anybody who knows what I am doing wrong?

The code is shown below:

```
def StockPredictor(stock, startdate, enddate, pricetype):
    
    #Get the stock quote
    df = web.DataReader(stock, data_source = 'yahoo', start=startdate, end=enddate)
    #df = pd.read_csv('StockData/TATA.csv')
    
    #Create a new dataframe with only the price type chosen
    data = df.filter([pricetype])
    dataset = data.values  #convert dataset into a numpy array
    training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * 0.80) #ik wil 80% van de dataset gebruiken om het LSTM model te trainen (naar boven afronden met math.ceil)
    
    #Scale the data (normalizing imput data) (helps the model)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))  #scaled_data allemaal waardes tussen 0 en 1
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)  #computes min and max values for scaling and transforms data based on these values
    
    #Create the training data set
    #Create the scaled training data set
    train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len , :]
    #split data into x_train and y_train datasets
    x_train, y_train = [], []  #x_train independent training feature, y dependent
    for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
        x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i,0])  #bevat de waardes van 60 vorige periodes 
        y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])    #bevat 61e waarde waarvan we willen dat model het voorspelt
    
    #Convert x_train and y_train to numpy arrays
    x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
    
    #reshape data (LSTM expects data to be 3D in form of no. of samples, no. of timestamps and no. of features) (x_train is now 2D)
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1], 1)) #reshape tot 3D, x_train.shape[0] = no of rows in 2D x_train, [1] is no of colums van 2D x_train
    
    #Build the LSTM model
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences= False))
    model.add(Dense(25))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error') #model has loss function and optimizer
    
    #training the model with the fit function
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1) #epoch is no of iterations of the dataset forth and backwarth in neural network
    
    #Create the testing data set
    #Create new array containing scale valuels from index
    test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60: , :]
    #create datasets x_test and y_test
    x_test = []
    y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
    for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
        x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i,0])
        
    #convert data into numpy array
    x_test = np.array(x_test)
    
    #Reshape data (zelfde uitleg als regel 65)
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
    
    #Get models predicted price values
    #predictions afhankelijk van x_test moeten zelfde values krijgen als y_test
    predictions = model.predict(x_test) #want predictions to contain same values as y_test
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions) #unscale the values
    
    #Get the RMSE (om het model te testen)
    rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(predictions - y_test)**2)
    rmse
    
    #Plot the data
    train = data[:training_data_len]
    valid = data[training_data_len:]
    valid['Predictions'] = predictions
        
    print('The RMSE for the training model =', rmse)
    
    new_df = df.filter([pricetype])
    #get the last 60 days
    last_60_days = new_df[-60:].values
    last_60_days_scaled = scaler.transform(last_60_days)
    #create empty list
    X_test = []
    #append past 60 days to list
    X_test.append(last_60_days)
    #Convert X_test to numpy array
    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    #reshape to 3D
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1],1))
    #Get predicted scaled price
    pred_price = model.predict(X_test)
    #undo scaling
    pred_price = scaler.inverse_transform(pred_price)
    print('Predicted price for the next day is :',pred_price)
    
    return pred_price 

allprices = []
for i in range(10):
    pred_price = StockPredictor()
    allprices.append(pred_price)
    
average_pred_price = sum(allprices) / len(allprices)
```

Comment: In this case stock was defined as: 'AAPL' , startdate as: '2012-01-01' , enddate as: '2021-03-14' and pricetype as 'Close'

Comment: Please do not use the comments for providing additional info; edit & update your post instead. Plus, for the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you here).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a min max scaler between `0` and `1`, where the defined highs are historical. Your LSTM model will predict a new high and when you `inverse_transform` the prediction, it will likely be higher than the min and max that has been fitted to the scaler.

Therefore the scaler is the likely culprit that is resulting in your predictions being a factor of 2x higher. Using a standard scaler might help, or without scaling at all.

#### Side Note

LSTMs to predict stock prices simply on price data will not work.

What is likely to happen is that your LSTM model will predict prices with a T+1 lag - predicting the price with a 1 day lag.

Price data inherently contains noise, brought about by retail traders and especially now with social sentiment trading. An LSTM is likely to overfit on historical noise and therefore is unrepresentative of future *"noises"*

For more information on the problem of noise, check out this link - https://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/06/marketnoise.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know that the LSTM model will indeed not be a good estimator of the stock prices. However, I was figuring out how to work with these algorithms for fun. Thanks again.